# Parse input and do action

Tags: parsing, haskell

We have a standard input like:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
1 3 2
5 3 2
...
```

Each line consists of exactly three numbers, for each line we'd like to compute the function value

```
f :: (Int, Int, Int) -> Int
```

and print the result. How to do that?

Comment: This looks like a homework problem, which is kind of awesome. What have you tried so far? What do you think will be part of the solution?

Comment: @JameySharp No no, even if it definitely looks like that, I'm learning Haskell on my own :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll point out some useful functions that will aid you in your quest:

```
readFile :: FilePath -> IO String

lines :: String -> [String]

words :: String -> [String]

print :: (Show a) => a -> IO ()
```

I recommend you open up a `ghci` sessions, experiment with those functions a little bit and see what they do, and try to mix them together in creative ways.  I'll give you a head start:

```
Prelude> str <- readFile "test.txt"
Prelude> print (length (lines str))
<The number of lines in the file "test.txt">
```

Comment: The other suggestion I'd add is that list comprehension syntax is very helpful for making this kind of task readable. It's especially convenient to use pattern matching: `[...| [a,b,c] <- map words (lines str)]`. Oh, and you'll need the `read` function.

Answer (score 2):

A straightforward solution:

```
tuple3 :: [Int] -> (Int,Int,Int)
tuple3 [x,y,z] = (x,y,z)

main = mapM_ print . map (f . tuple3 . map read . words) . lines =<< getContents
```

I still don't understand why to use a tuple as the argument, it causes that ugly conversion.

Comment: And if `f` were `f :: Int->Int->Int->Int`? How would it change the main?

Comment: @Martin it won't be neat anyway, but converting from a list to a tuple is ugly: it can't be guaranteed that the list has required amount of elements, the resulting tuple will be redundant (three equal types on end), so it is fraught with run-time exceptions. From aesthetic point of view, it's like comparing apples and oranges.

Tuples and lists are objects of quite different type nature in Haskell (unlike Python): tuple is a fixed-size collection of items of any type (and I suspect it exists in compile-time only), list is a run-time sequence of items of the same type.